# «Стероидные гормоны — в частности(,) тестостерон — синтезируются...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вводные-слова

> Стероидные гормоны — в частности(,) тестостерон — синтезируются из холестерина надпочечниками.

Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте? Интересует именно вариант с тире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Справочники пишут следующее.

[**2. Вводное слово и обособленный оборот**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2) (Грамота.ру)

> А) Если вводное слово стоит **в начале обособленного оборота** – запятые ставятся **перед вводным словом и после всего обособленного оборота. После вводного слова запятая не ставится.**
>
> **Примечание 1**. Если оборот заключен **в скобки**, то стоящее в его начале или конце вводное слово отделяется запятой **по общему правилу**: *Был он казахом с почти русской фамилией и русским **(кажется, начальным)** образованием.* Ю. Домбровский, Хранитель древностей.

[**§ 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122) (Розенталь)

> Если сочетание ***в частности*** находится в составе присоединительной конструкции (в начале ее или в конце), то оно **выделяется запятыми вместе с этой конструкцией**: *Многие народы и народности, населяющие Россию, **в частности народы Крайнего Севера**, получили письменность сравнительно недавно.*

Здесь же, в пункте **10**, говорится о случаях употребления **тире** при вводных словах и сочетаниях. Ни под один из этих случаев предложение из вопроса не подходит. Выделение оборота с двух сторон тире кажется избыточным, хотя, на мой взгляд, и не является ошибкой.

**Предпочтительные варианты**:

*Стероидные гормоны, в частности тестостерон, синтезируются из холестерина надпочечниками.*

*Стероидные гормоны (в частности, тестостерон) синтезируются из холестерина надпочечниками.*

**Дополнение**

С момента вопроса прошла почти неделя, и я снова и снова обращался к этой теме, так как однозначного ответа об отделении вводного слова внутри оборота, обособленного с двух сторон тире, не нашёл. Можно ли считать тире и скобки равносильными знаками в данном случае? По-моему, тире находится где-то между запятыми и скобками. Последние являются более "строгими" знаками: всё, что заключено в них, пишется по правилам обычных предложений.

Национальный корпус русского языка по запросу "***в частности***" выдаёт 9648 документов (там, естественно, пишут кто во что горазд). Проанализировав 1010 из них, я нашёл только 34, соответствующих нашему примеру: **28** с запятой и **6** без неё. Но потом я обратил внимание на то, что все они относятся к нашему веку. Поставил настройки по дате, и оказалось, что предложений с ***в частности*** там всего лишь 6 штук XIX века и 363 — XX. **И ни в одном из них эти обороты с помощью тире не обособляются.** А вот обособление начинается с 2001-го. Привожу некоторые **примеры без запятой** (хотя в той же газете «Известия» можно встретить и обратное):

*Министр иностранных дел... заявил, что небольшие группы... скрываются в ряде районов страны ― в частности в провинции Пактия.* [Удары возмездия и вокруг них. Афганистан: Последние события // «Известия», 2001.12.27]

*Первым делом я метнулся к окну ― в «Матросской тишине» окна следственного корпуса выходят на волю, и можно узреть удивительные для арестанта картины ― в частности проход девчонки в юбчонке.* [Андрей Рубанов. Гонзо (2010)]

*По самым разным причинам ― в частности по той, о которой я сейчас говорила.* [Иван Мартов. От толкинистов до попаданцев (2016.10.13)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** от 29.10.2023

Нашёл [**аналогичный вопрос**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=311344):

> Добрый день. Если обособленный оборот выделен тире с двух сторон, а в его начале стоит вводное слово, то нужно ли ставить запятую после вводного слова? Нигде не встречала правила об этом. А примеров много.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Действительно, подобные примеры в справочниках не приводятся. Здесь можно рекомендовать следовать общему правилу выделения вводных конструкций. В [параграфе 93](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/#id-7%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%C2%A793) полного академического справочника «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина (М., 2006 и след.) приводится пример: *В иных озерах (например, в Черненьком) вода напоминает блестящую тушь* (Пауст.). Полагаем, что иной способ оформления вставной конструкции в этом предложении — с помощью тире, а не скобок — не повлияет на постановку знаков препинания при вводном слове: *В иных озерах — например, в Черненьком — вода напоминает блестящую тушь.*